# how to bind an event handler to request promise to close a socket when resource is too big?

Tags: javascript, node.js, xmlhttprequest, request-promise

Using request-promise I wonder how I can close the socket early when the resource exceeds 2000 bits. From the .on('data', callback) event handler I would like to close the socket and jump to the code within then(). I already tried this.abort() but it didn't work. For now on, the event handle works and takes the number of bits but I can close the socket from the event when the bit size triggers the if condition.

```
var request = require('request');
var rp = require('request-promise-native');

var size = 0;
const MAX_SIZE = 2000;

rp
.get('https://sitecozy.com/screenshot.png')
.on('data',(ok)=>
{console.log(size)
size += ok.length;

    if (size > MAX_SIZE) {
        console.log("Aborting this request as it exceeds max size")
    // I wish to close the socket and trigger then() from here.
    }

}

)
.then(function (htmlString) {
   console.log("good")
})
.catch(function (err) {
   console.log("bad") 
});;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have succeeded in doing it using the stand request package and wrapping it in a promise. I wished to use request-promise because there are already lots of nested blocks in my code:

```
const request = require('request');

var size =0;
var maxLength = 8175;

new Promise ((resolve,reject)=>{
var jo = request("https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/9/9b/Sternwarte_Darmstadt_HDR_Panorama_10MB_-_Photographed_by_James_Breitenstein.jpg")

.on('response',(ok)=>{
jo.responseHeaders = ok.headers;})

.on('data',(ok)=>{
size+=ok.length;
if (size > maxLength){
console.log("DATA",size);resolve(jo.response);jo.abort();}})

.on('end',function(ok){console.log("END");})})

.then(function (ok) {
    console.log("ok then",ok)
})
.catch(function (err) {
  console.log("error",err)

});
```